# what is the spring-web module compatible with tomcat 10

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, classcastexception, tomcat10

what is the spring-web module version compatible with tomcat 10?

Spring web Application is running on tomcat 9.x and its fail with ClassCastException ad tomcat 10 using jakarta API.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy cannot be cast to jakarta.servlet.Filter

Answer (score 3):

There is none, currently, none of the spring 5 versions support Jakarta packages.
They did say however that in version 6 they will tho, but for now it supports Javax packages.
There might be some workaround, I know I had to test if Spring 4 works with JDK11, it does, but Spring suggests using Spring 5 for JDK11.

For Spring MVC 5, the Spring MVC DispatcherServlet has a dependency on the javax.servlet.* package namespace. This is using the Java EE 8 javax package naming. Since Tomcat 10 is based on Jakarta EE 9, the packages for javax naming are not supported. This explains why Spring MVC 5 does not work on Tomcat 10.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/25276

Comment: As a workaround [Tomcat Migration Tool](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-migration.cgi) can convert Spring 5.x libraries to Jakarta EE 9, but I wouldn't use it on a production server.

Comment: Any alteration of Spring libraries can lead to issues and also zero support from spring if they occur. If they wanted they would have made it compatible. But to be honest, I personally, do not see why would anyone strictly need to use 10 instead of 9. Just use 9 as intended until Spring 6 is out. Using the latest versions of anything was always my least favorite trend.